# How to find and replace whole words in a MySQL text field?

Tags: mysql

I have a sentence:

"How to find and replace word in text from mysql database?"

And MySQL table words, with to 3 column id, word and replaceWord. 
I have more than 4000 words in databese.

Table:

```
id     word     replaceWord
 1     text     sentence
 2     word     letter
 3     mysql    MySQL
 4     ..       ...
 5     ..       ...
 6     ..       ...
```

Result:

"How to find and replace **letter** in **sentence** from **MySQL** database?"

I know how to do this without database, but i need database.

```
 <?php
$text="How to find and replace word in text from mysql database?";
$replaceWord=array(  "text" => "sentence", "word" => "letter", "mysql" => "MySQL");
echo strtr($tekst, $replaceWord);
?>
```

Comment: I spy "context" becoming "consentence", or "sword" being changed to "sletter"

Comment: Hey @MarkBaker, considering your comment in here, do you have any solution in mind that covers those cases?

Answer (score 4):

### MySQL 8+

Can use the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(the_text,
                      CONCAT('(^|\\W)', text_to_find, '(\\W|$)'),
                      CONCAT('$1', replacement_text, '$2')) AS replaced_text
FROM the_table;
```

See [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f1f90b877901db0f9692b2dece7a0eb).

**Explanation:** `\W` is a regular expression syntax for a non-word character (the backslash needs to be escaped hence `\\W`). Alternatively, `^` caters for the very start of the text and `$` the very end of the text. `$1` and `$2` put these characters from the parenthesized capturing groups back into the replacement text.

### MySQL versions prior to 8

If you are forced to use an earlier version of MySQL it is quite a lot trickier but still technically possible using a custom written regular expression replacer - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826#38660574) for details.

---

### MariaDB 10.0.5+

As pointed out by Paul Spiegel in the comments, the only difference in MariaDB versions supporting [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) is the use of `\\1` and `\\2` instead of `$1` and `$2` to identify the capturing groups:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(the_text,
                      CONCAT('(^|\\W)', text_to_find, '(\\W|$)'),
                      CONCAT('\\1', replacement_text, '\\2')) AS replaced_text
FROM the_table;
```

See [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1610b05d5e7f5674491cf42d33c0e3e5).

Comment: Fortunately, I'm running MariaDB 10.3.18 and it does support [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/). I'll give this solution a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @GustavoStraube - Note that in MariaDB you have  to use `\\1` and `\\2` instead of `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel, have now added a section for MariaDB to the answer.

Comment: @SteveChambers I still have some questions on this solution. Could you join the following chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201727/discussion-on-how-to-find-and-replace-whole-words-in-a-mysql-text-field

Answer (score 3):

```
update YourTable, Words
    set YourTable.YourColumn = replace(YourTable.YourColumn, Words.word, Words.replaceWord)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select REPLACE(fieldOrString, SearchString, ReplaceString) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a terrible idea in terms of scalability: you could just iterate over the sentence word by word, and on each one do a query for where the word exists in 'word'. If it does exist (returns data) then do a replace with the content from 'replaceWord'

**EDIT**: Not totally database based, but more so than your current version.

Answer (score 0):

```
//load all replacements
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YourTableNameHere");
//replace all words
$words = array();
$replacewords =array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $words[] = $row['word'];
    $replacewords[] = $row['replaceword'];
}
$text = str_replace($words,$replacewords);
```

If you need preg_replace as well:
You must add the column isPattern to your table, then you can do this:

```
//load all replacements
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YourTableNameHere");
//replace all words
$words = array();
$replacewords = array();
$preg_words = array();
$preg_replacewords = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!$row['isPattern']){        
        $words[] = $row['word'];
        $replacewords[] = $row['replaceword'];
    }
    else{
        $preg_words[] = $row['word'];
        $preg_replacewords[] = $row['replaceword'];
    }
}
$text = str_replace($words,$replacewords);
$text = $preg_replace($preg_words,$preg_replacewords);
```

Comment: I have more than 4000 words, is there a another solution?

Comment: updated it so it just needs one call of str_replae. Do you want to do this on PHP or do you want to do this with SQL? Im not sure that I did get you right ;)

Comment: In PHP, thank you, but i have one problem. Script realplayer all word with last in database. So my firs sentence will look like: "How to find and replace MySQL in MySQL from MySQL database?"

Comment: OK, i figured it, only add [] to the $replacewords. I have several exceptions. In my language we have a word "da li", and if i replace "dali" with "da li" then i have a problem in name of "salvatore dali"="salvatore da li". Can you help me with this and I will stop bother you?! :) Thanks again.

Comment: No not really. I you exactly know the exceptions you could try searching for patterns instead o wirds (e.g any word taht is NOT"salvador" followed by "dali"), but I can hardly explain poattern search in a short answer. I will edit my post so you can use pregreplace to searh or patterns but you will have to learn how to use preg_replace for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will endeavor to learn how to use preg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

After I started to implement my own query based on the [answer by @SteveChambers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628023/1128918) I found the substitution happened only once per result row. For example, given the table records mentioned by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4829281/1128918), this query:

```
SELECT 
    word,
    replaceWord,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        'How to find and replace word in text from mysql database?', 
        CONCAT('(?i)(^|\\W)', word, '(\\W|$)'),
        CONCAT('\\1', replaceWord, '\\2')
    ) AS replaced_text 
FROM 
    words 
WHERE 
    'How to find and replace word in text from mysql database?' REGEXP CONCAT('(?i)(^|\\W)', word, '(\\W|$)');
```

would return distinct 3 rows of results:

```
word  | replaceWord | replaced_text
------+-------------+--------------
text  | sentence    | How to find and replace letter in text from mysql database?
word  | letter      | How to find and replace word in sentence from mysql database?
mysql | MySQL       | How to find and replace word in text from MySQL database?
```

Notice each row has only one word replaced.

After some discussion, we got to the conclusion that recursion was required. I managed to achieve that without a procedure or function with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    (@i := @i + 1) AS i, 
    @tmp := IFNULL(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            @tmp, 
            CONCAT('(?i)(^|\\W)', word, '(\\W|$)'), 
            CONCAT('\\1', replaceWord, '\\2')
        ),
        @tmp
    ) AS replaced_text 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            @tmp := 'How to find and replace word in text from mysql database?',
            @i := 0
    ) x
LEFT JOIN 
    words 
ON 
    @tmp REGEXP CONCAT('(?i)(^|\\W)', word, '(\\W|$)') 
ORDER BY i DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This query recursively replaces each word in the original string, accumulating the replacements. It uses an index (`@i`) to number the rows. Finally, it returns only the last result (greater index), which contains all accumulate replacements.

It uses a `LEFT JOIN` combined with `IFNULL` to return the original string in case no substitution is made.

Answer (score -1):

$tablesarray include column array where you want to search Any word or letter

$PDO database connection

```
    $tablesarray['tablename1']= array('column1' ,'column2' );
    $tablesarray['tablename2']= array('column1' ,'column2' );
    
    $wordstoreplace = ['searchedwordOrLetter1'=>'replacedwordOrLetter1' , 'searchedwordOrLetter2'=>'replacedwordOrLetter2' ]
    foreach($repairkeyarray as $table => $columns){
        foreach($columns as $column){
            foreach($wordstoreplace as $searched => $replaced ){
                $PDO->query("update $table set `$column` = replace(`$column`, '$searched', '$replaced') WHERE `$column` LIKE '%$searched%';");
                @$PDO->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```